# How to remove sub-strings from list lines that start with a certain character sequence and generate an output file

Tags: python, list

So here is my task: I have this file.txt with the following text lines:

```
CODE 1 DXVB: TLH - 188JSUY23000DI12
CODE 2 DXVB: DDH - 6SJ27GFKKKK29R82
CODE 3 DXVB: TSS - 9S676J1J87S88WJ2
WARNING 55DE2: CODE 4 DXVB: ASE - UDY239FJM9S7J25F
CODE 5 DXVB: RRE - DFUA83J398D7G928
WARNING 33E65: CODE 6 DXVB: RGR - FDS89987432JHOFE
WARNING 13WWQ: CODE 7 DXVB: HTR - DF7A09883J319SST
CODE 8 DXVB: YUY - 88324J269S7JJWQI
```

As you can see, some lines start with the sub-string "WARNING #####: " where ##### is an unique code. My task is to read this file in Python using

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

then edit the list so all sub-strings with the above format to be deleted and the final list look to like this:

```
CODE 1 DXVB: TLH - 188JSUY23000DI12
CODE 2 DXVB: DDH - 6SJ27GFKKKK29R82
CODE 3 DXVB: TSS - 9S676J1J87S88WJ2
CODE 4 DXVB: ASE - UDY239FJM9S7J25F
CODE 5 DXVB: RRE - DFUA83J398D7G928
CODE 6 DXVB: RGR - FDS89987432JHOFE
CODE 7 DXVB: HTR - DF7A09883J319SST
CODE 8 DXVB: YUY - 88324J269S7JJWQI
```

The list will finally be written on a new .txt file called output.txt

Basically every list line that starts with "WARINIG" should have its first 15 characters (white spaces counted) deleted. The ##### code is always different and the file.txt will have thousands of lines. I am new to Python. Thank you!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. You have to research the problem, try to figure out a solution, and come back with a specific question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this. Open the input file, read it line per line, substitute 'WARNING ...' by an empty string, and write that to an output file.

```
import re

rgx = r"^WARNING\s\w+:\s"
with open('file.txt', 'r') as fin, open('file_out.txt', 'w') as fout:
  for line in fin:
    fout.write(re.sub(rgx, "", line) + "\n")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, regex is the easiest solution indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You could create new array and check every line of original array if there's 'WARNING' in than line, slice it at second `' '` and then add that line to new array, if there isn't warning in that line add it unmodified.

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    new_lines = [' '.join(i.split()[2:]) if 'WARNING'in i else i for i in lines]

with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(new_lines))
```

Output:

```
CODE 1 DXVB: TLH - 188JSUY23000DI12
CODE 2 DXVB: DDH - 6SJ27GFKKKK29R82
CODE 3 DXVB: TSS - 9S676J1J87S88WJ2
CODE 4 DXVB: ASE - UDY239FJM9S7J25F
CODE 5 DXVB: RRE - DFUA83J398D7G928
CODE 6 DXVB: RGR - FDS89987432JHOFE
CODE 7 DXVB: HTR - DF7A09883J319SST
CODE 8 DXVB: YUY - 88324J269S7JJWQI
```